# REGEX rejecting simple alphamumeric

Tags: regex, alphanumeric

I don't get it; this should be simple:

Why does this text box entry:

```
Foo 2010
```

Validated by this REGEX:

```
ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9 -_!]+$"
```

Throw an invalid entry error? It is intended to allow alphamumerics, spaces, dashes, underscores and exclamation marks.

REGEX gives me a headache ...

Comment: Hum.. there is a space between **Foo** and **2010** which of course will not match, no?

Answer (score 3):

The dash `-` should be placed right after `[` or placed before `]` or escaped with `\`,
otherwise it'll be treated as a class range metacharacter.

Try this: `ValidationExpression="^[-a-zA-Z0-9 _!]+$"`

Comment: Thanks Nick! Thanks Bruno! Worked great.